# How to can we map Java Unit data type with C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on some sdk binding project from Java/Kotlin(Android) to Xamarin(Android). All classes binding is generated automatically as I add my .aar library file to binding project, but some of the classes has some constructor which has data type ()->Unit = {}
. It is not generating binding for these type of constructors so I need to map it manually but don't know how can I map this type of data type in xamarin?

```java
 @JvmOverloads
 @JvmStatic
 fun registerUser(email: String, userId: String? = null, name: String? = null,
                     attributes: HashMap<String, Any>? = null, company: HashMap<String,Any>? = null,
                     success: ()->Unit = {}, failure: ()->Unit = {}) {
    ...
 }

 @JvmStatic
 @JvmOverloads
 fun logoutUser(then: ()->Unit = {}) {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Had you used the Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib NuGet according to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-kotlin-library/walkthrough)?  ()->Unit = {} is only used in the Kotlin to replace the interface as a parameter in the java.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Yes I have used Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib nuget. if you can share any code snippet for this it will be very helpful.  All binding is working correctly but just success & failure callback are get ignored. Can I add that ignored parameters with Metadata.xml ?